# OutLook Mail Rest API --> See if the message is a reply

Tags: email, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I am trying to get a way to see if a message that i get using the Outlook Rest API using this url `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/messages('{messageid}')` and seing if it is a reply. Normaly it would be from the Thread Id but the API doesn´t send one.

Is there anyway to see if the message is a reply?

Comment: does anyone know how to solve this problem ? i have similar issues too but not in graph api, my problem in outlook api

Answer (score 0):

API has one 'ConversationId' field. You can use that to group the messages.

```
{
    ...
    "ConversationId": "AQQkADAwAT..."
    ...
}
```

Comment: `ConversationId` is Ok, but what about ordering of messages? Can you plz explain?

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60048538/3892957

Use GET `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$expand=SingleValueExtendedProperties($filter=(Id%20eq%20'Integer%200x1081'))`

If a Message had been replied to you would see a result like

```
        "singleValueExtendedProperties": [
        {
            "id": "Integer 0x1081",
            "value": "102"
        }
       ]
```